# what program should I use to create this

Tags: html, flash, video

I want to create a teaching video that stops after each mini explanations and poses a multiple choice question for the user. If they are right the next mini explanation begins, if wrong the previous explanation replays. I am no programmer and probably would have used flash in the old days. But as it's not supported so widely now, I don't know what program to use to create an html 5 video/ quiz

Answer (score -1):

Though your question is really general and it seems like you did no research on this yourself, I will give you a short hint: Have a look at this https://h5p.org/interactive-video

Next time use google/duckduckgo/ecosia please.

Comment: I did actually do research and only came up with Adobe Animate so thought it may be easier to ask people who already familiar with a range of programs, If you asked me what's the best way to learn Spanish I would be happy to answer as it is my field of expertise - I would not expect you to exhaust Google resources first. I very much appreciate your link though. Thanks